# how to not add class=“” to last element in vuejs for loop

Tags: vue.js

remove tailwind class when last iteration of loop index in vuejs template.

**in template**

```
v-for="(service, index) in getAllServices.home_page_services" :key="index"
```

**in script**

```
<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
        this.$store.dispatch("getHomePageContent")
    },
    computed: {
        getAllServices(){
            return this.$store.getters.getContentFormGetters
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i can solve it

```
:class="{ 'lg:border-r-2 lg:border-blue-650': index < getAllServices.home_page_services.length - 1 }"
```